# Get a list of specific tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is it possible to set an attribute to specific tables/classes in EF and then query a list of those tables out based on that attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute the their `partial` classes. Then get a list of types with that attribute in the current assembly

```
Assembly thisAsm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var tableTypes = thisAsm.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsDefined(typeof(MyAttribute), false));
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the IsDefined method, I got it working using the DbContext class directly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it working without using Assembly:

```
public class FoodAttribute : Attribute { }
public class Fruit { }
public class Coin { }
public class Cereal { }

public class FooContext : DbContext {
    [Food]
    public virtual DbSet<Fruit> Fruits { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Coin> Coins { get; set; }
    [Food]
    public virtual DbSet<Cereal> Cereals { get; set; }
}
```

To get a list of tables with the attribute Food:

```
var tableList = typeof(FooContext).GetProperties()
    .Where(n => n.IsDefined(typeof(ClientTraitAttribute)))
    .Select(n => n.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name).ToList();
```

Thanks Yuriy for showing me the IsDefined method! :D

Comment: Doesn't that DbContext file get auto generated? Unless you're doing it manually.

Comment: Right, I'm doing Code First from database (i.e. Database First) so the files only generate once.